# Is translation of the following excerpt from Appayya Dikshita's Brahma Sutra Bhashya available in English?

Tags: translation-request, brahma-sutras, resource, commentary, appayya-dikshitar

Can anyone provide English translation of the following texts which are from Appayya Dikshita's Brahmasutra Bhasya? Has this text been translated into English?

> णाजातशत्रुणा का लोके माह्मणस्य महावि विदिषयोपसनस्य
> शिष्यभावेनानुजनमनमस्य तं पाणी गृहीत्वेव मष्टिमातोत्यापन्त प्रति
> प्रस्थितमियानानम्। “तत इद बाकि समिपाणिः प्रतिमोत्क यानीति तं
> होगाचावातशत्रु प्रतिलोम मेव तत्स्यावत् क्षत्रियो ब्राह्मणानुपनदेहि
> ज्येन वाशापविण्यामीति तं पाणावभिपय प्रयवान तो सुतं पुरुषमी सु''रिति ॥
> ३६ ॥३७॥ ३८॥ ब्रह्मपराणां पुनः किमर्थ विविदित्याव्यात- अपरं होति।
> तुम्यामिति । चनु शूद्राणां वेद्भवणादिषु दण्डविधानेन निषेधावगमेऽपि
> वेदियोग वेदाध्ययनरहितानां श्रीणामेष विद्याइनं किम स्यात् ? तस्मात् –'न
> शूद्राय मति दयानोच्छिष्टं न इविष्कृतम् । न चास्योपदिशेद्धर्म न चास्य
> मतमादिशेत् प्र यो अस्य नर्म साचष्टे यवेवादिशति मतम् । सोऽतं नाम तमः
> सद् तेनैव गच्छति ॥ इति शहाणां ये देशेषिकर्मा ये सामान्य धर्माः
> सहसाधारण्यास्तव्यतिरिक्तवैदिकार्थमाइणे सह तेनैव शुण गुरोर्नरकपातोफेः
> कथं तर्हि माने तेमां पुराणेतिहासादि लविद्यानुष्ठानाभ्युपगम:
> "श्रावधतुरो वर्णनिति" स्मरणात् । तस्म दृष्टालाय पुराणेतिहास
> शैववैष्णवागमवर्णितय जमानकर्तृकवैदिकमा पारणानपेक्षतनियनोपासनादि
> संभवतीति तदभिप्रामः । ननुदानस्य विनायसाभारण्योधिः 'दानं च दद्यात्
> शङ्गोऽपि पाकशेयजेत च इति स्मृत्यन्तर विरुद्धेव्याशा
> व्याच–द्विजातीनामिति । दिमादीनाम ध्ययनमज्या दानमित्येतदनन्तरं
> ब्राह्मणस्याधिकारः प्रवचनयाजनप्रतिपदा ति प्रतिहस
> ब्राह्मणाखापारण्यवचनात् पूर्यवाक्ये दानस्य प्रतिक्षण्येन नर्षिक
> साधारण्यमात्रं विवक्षितं न तु शुहस्य दाननिषेध इति मायः ॥ इति नवमयपशु
> प्राधिकरणम्

Comment: Questions asking for pure translation are not in the scope of this site. I am voting to close this question as off topic .

Comment: These texts are from which Hindu scripture?

Comment: Yes it is form appayya's Brahma sutra bhashya

Comment: ok .. I have edited accordingly. And I don't think that now the question is off topic. @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

Comment: Yes Rickross . do you know any translator plz tell to translate

Comment: No I don't know ... @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud

Comment: OK @rickross I will wait do any one amswr this

Comment: Yes someone might answer @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud